# Map Reduce Removing Duplicates

Tags: mapreduce

I have been given a large text file and want to find the number of different words that start with each letter. I am trying to understand input and output values for map and reduce functions.

I understand a simpler problem which does not need to deal with duplicate words: determine the frequency with which each letter of the alphabet starts a word in the text using map reduce.

```
Map input: <0, “everyday i am city in tomorrow easy over school i iterate tomorrow city community”>

Map output: [<e,1>,<i,1>,<a,1>,<c,1>,<i,1>,<t,1>,<e,1>,<o,1>,<s,1>,<i,1>,<i,1>,<t,1>,<c,1>,<c,1>]

Reduce input: <a,[1]>,<c,[1,1,1]>,<e,[1,1]>,<i,[1,1,1,1]>,<o,[1]>,<s,[1]>,<t,[1,1]>

Reduce output: [<a,1>,<c,3>,<e,2>,<i,4>,<o,1>,<s,1>,<t,2>]
```

For the above problem the words 'i' 'city' and 'tomorrow' appear more than once so my final output should be:

```
Reduce output: [<a,1>,<c,2>,<e,2>,<i,3>,<o,1>,<s,1>,<t,1>]
```

I am unsure of how I would ensure duplicate words are remove in the above problem (would it be done in a pre processing phase or could it be implemented on either map or reduce functions). If I could get help understanding the map and reduce outputs of the new problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two map-reduce passes:

1. find all the distinct word by using word as a map output and in reduce outputting each word once
2. you already solved - find frequency of each initial letter on each unique word.

Alternatively, since there are not many unique words you can cache them in mapper and output each one (or its first letter) only once and the reduce will be identical to your simpler problem. Actually, no, that won't work because same words can appear in different mappers. But you can still cache the words in mapper in the first solution and output each word only once per mapper - a little bit less traffic between map and reduce.

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am looking for. Just to understand correctly: I would then have 2 mapreduce (i.e. map->reduce->map->reduce) phases? The first to remove duplicate words and the second to find the frequency (simpler problem explained above)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help,

```
let str = "everyday i am city in tomorrow easy over school i iterate tomorrow city community"

let duplicatesRemoved = Set(str.split(separator: " "))
```

**Output:**

```
["city", "community", "tomorrow", "easy", "everyday", "over", "in", "iterate", "i", "am", "school"]
```

And maybe you don't need those map statements and can achieve something like this,

**Code**

```
var varCount = [Character: Int]()
for subStr in duplicatesRemoved {
    if let firstChar = subStr.first {
        varCount[firstChar] = (varCount[firstChar] ?? 0) + 1
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
["i": 3, "t": 1, "e": 2, "c": 2, "s": 1, "a": 1, "o": 1]
```

Comment: I guess what I am trying to achieve is a full solution using only mapreduce. The preprocessing phase is a simple solution that works for the above example. I guess it would be less effective if multiple files were introduced using multiple nodes.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can do this,

>`Map input: <0, “everyday i am city in tomorrow easy over school i iterate tomorrow city community”>`

>`Map output: [<easy,1>,<i,1>,<tomorrow,1>,<tomorrow,1>,...]`

>` Reduce input: <easy,[1]>,<city,[1,1]>,<tomorrow,[1,1]>...>`

>`Reduce output: [<a,1>,<c,2>,<t,1>...]`